# Apache - how to test tcp_tw_reuse effect?

Tags: apache, reusability, connection, time-wait

I'm struggling with an Apache server which runs out of ports. I believe my problem are connections in the TIME_WAIT state. I've tried net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=40 and net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1. How can I test the effect of net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse before enabling this on production? Any hints?

Comment: did you find any option to test it ?